# Should I have a separate account for "answering questions" and "asking questions"?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

It has happened me 3 times that my account was closed for asking bad questions.

I made my reputation in long period of time and then, after a few questions with downvotes, my account was suspended. It happened again and when I reached few reputation, my account again got banned from asking questions.

I can't say if those questions should not be asked.

I have seen that many times similar questions have over 30 votes and I get downvotes. Even though that was not directly programming-related.

E.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419235/anyone-know-of-a-good-python-based-web-crawler-that-i-could-use).

I had these sort of questions closed many times.

Also I think that if the same question was asked by a person with more reputation, like above 5000, then it gets more votes and if I ask the same question I get downvotes. There is no consistency. I think those questions should also be closed. Because as per rules if they are not really programming-related they should be closed.

But anyhow, now I have felt that I should have a separate account - one for answering questions and another for asking questions - so that I don't have to worry about the reputation earned over a long period of time by answering questions. Is it ok like that?

Comment: I'm curious why you think you _can't_ learn to write questions that won't be deleted? If you're asking, you obviously want to learn; so why not learn how to [Write the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)?

Comment: Note that the question you reference is from **2** years ago when the rules were somewhat different. It shouldn't really be used as a guide for what's on topic now. It would also help your argument if you linked to your questions that have been closed.

Comment: I haveseen that 5 down votes closed my account. When my question was closed i had 1 -ve vote . i could not delete the question and in 2 days i get -4 votes for that question. In next questions i get -1 votes and my account got closed. The questions i need to ask sometime is which thing i should use a or b. Thatsometimes got closed and sometimes i get many +votes. i really don't understood the theory

Comment: Account got closed, or suspended from asking questions?

Comment: @forsvarir i mean suspend . i think it actually means closing. because then what would i need account for if i can't ask questions. i think its better if u guys delete that account rather suspended

Comment: @user, you really *really* need to work on your written English. That doesn't mean your questions still won't get downvoted, but it would certainly help. I don't mean be perfect, but avoid txtspk (like u instead of you), and remember to capitalize your 'i's. You may feel that it's a minor detail, but it is the kind of detail that implies that you don't care enough to craft a question properly.

Comment: @Benjol Actually english is not my first language so its hard for me but I will try that

Comment: @user782234: You *might* want the account for answering questions... My understanding is that if you're suspended from asking questions, that doesn't stop you answering. If you accrue sufficient reputation from answering questions well, the account will be able to ask questions again in the future...

Comment: @user - Most Internet users have a first language other than English.

Comment: @forsvarir . What are rules of suspending sccount. i mean how much downvotes so that i can keep an eye what do i need to do rather than suspending straight away. also how much rep i need more if i want to ask questions again

Comment: @user782234, do you already have a separate account for answering questions? Because I can't find any in your current account.

Comment: @User, your capitalized i's ran out rather quickly :)

Comment: English grammar isn't really the problem. It's spelling. Either you need to proofread what you type more carefully before clicking "send", or you should download a browser with an integrated spell-check. Chrome is nice.

Comment: @user: Are you sure you are suspended? Suspension never goes automatically. It is always "activated" by a moderator. If you are just banned from asking questions (this is an automatic process of which the details are deliberately unknown), you should still be able to answer questions.

Comment: @All Now why did my this question get -10 votes. Can anyone explain that. Its really funny , asking for why i get -ve votes also got me -10 votes. Am I banned from asking questions here as well

Comment: @user782234 - on meta, votes up or down mean that the person placing the vote either agrees or disagrees with you. A large number of people have disagreed with your post, that's all it means.

Comment: A suspension is never about the account, it is always about the *person behind the account*. It's not like people consistently ask bad questions because they are logged in, they ask bad questions because that's what they know how to ask. As such, having multiple accounts will just lead to multiple bans, and actually, having multiple accounts *just to get around a suspension* usually leads to a lot longer, or even permanent, suspension. Don't do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your questions keep getting voted down to the point where you lose all your rep or have an account suspended then, and I mean this in the nicest possible way, you are doing something wrong.

One or two votes one way or another might just be a result of "drive by" voting but consistent patterns of up or down voting are a comment by the community on the quality of  what you've posted.

Now I'm a SF regular rather than a SO regular but looking at your account on SO, you've asked 6 questions that I can see, 3 of which were off topic for SO - so that's a suggestion that you need to work on your question asking in itself: If you're consistently posting off-topic questions then that isn't going to end well.

The other 3 got answers, though 2 of them appear to be subjective to me ("*what is the easiest...*" and "*which should I choose...*" are nearly always signs of a subjective/poor quality question on SF in my opinion).

The SO/SF/SU sites are rather intolerant of poor quality questions and especially of people who keep asking them over and over again without learning. We have to be because of the volumes of traffic. This isn't because people want you to leave or enjoy seeing people get their account suspended or lose their reputation. We want the sites and the people on them to flourish - but you have to put some work into improving.